# Cache system always generates the same cache for specified view

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5

I have very annoying problem with cache system builtin Laravel.

This cache system generates the same cache for specified view! Even when I have been done some changes in this view and then I clears cache (via php artisan and manually etc) it generates THE SAME new cache file for this view.

Let me take you an example code (maybe I'm doing something bad but ...)

Controller:

```
class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function manage()
    {
        return view('administration::users.manage');
    }

}
```

View:

```
@extends('administration::layouts.master')

@section('content')
<div class="normalheader transition animated fadeIn">
    <div class="hpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <a class="small-header-action" href="">
                <div class="clip-header">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
                </div>
            </a>

            <div id="hbreadcrumb" class="pull-right m-t-lg">
                <ol class="hbreadcrumb breadcrumb">
                    {!! Breadcrumbs::render('module.administration.users.manage') !!}
                </ol>
            </div>
            <h2 class="font-light m-b-xs">
                Users
            </h2>
            <small>Loading buttons</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content animate-panel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="hpanel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Dashboard Home TEST
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Content of Dashboard TEST
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

Cache file (always the same, independently of changes)

```
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
<div class="normalheader transition animated fadeIn">
    <div class="hpanel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <a class="small-header-action" href="">
                <div class="clip-header">
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>
                </div>
            </a>

            <div id="hbreadcrumb" class="pull-right m-t-lg">
                <ol class="hbreadcrumb breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Interface</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <span>Loading buttons</span>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <h2 class="font-light m-b-xs">
                Ladda
            </h2>
            <small>Loading buttons</small>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content animate-panel">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="hpanel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Dashboard Home
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    Content of Dashboard
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('administration::layouts.master', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

As you can see, I changed the `Content of Dashboard` -> `Content of Dashboard TEST` without any changes.

I have disabled the opcache and other things, cache in .env is set to an array

What I can do more to solve this irritating problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `opcache` or laravel caching. This is the blade view engine.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several reasons why this isn't working.

The way blade works is it checks when the `*.blade.php` file is last edited, if this is later than the compiled file, the blade file is compiled again. A reason could be that your computer is in another timezone than your server and so, Laravel thinks the files shouldn't be compiled. Try setting the timezone of your server to the same timezone as the computer you are developing on.

Another problem can be that the `/storage` folder of your project is not writeable. Your web server has to have write access to this folder and its sub folders.

Comment: I changed the timezone to the properly for my computer and also /storage is writable, but problem still exists.

Comment: Try using `php artisan view:clear` on your webserver, this will clear all compiled views.